# Android app not compatible by any device

Tags: android, cordova, google-play, android-manifest, phonegap-build

We have published an iOS version of our app successfully, but Android is failing. We have deployed it into the Google Play store, but there we get the message that it is compatible with 0 Android devices (which is not a good thing obviously). The following file is the `AndroidManifest.xml` file found in the APK after compilation on PhonegapBuild (so this is the APK we send to the Google Play store).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:installLocation="internalOnly" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="com.myapp.mobileapp" platformBuildVersionCode="22" platformBuildVersionName="5.1.1-1819727">
    <supports-screens android:anyDensity="true" android:largeScreens="true" android:normalScreens="true" android:resizeable="true" android:smallScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.setParameters"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
    <permission android:name="com.myapp.mobileapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.myapp.mobileapp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:configChanges="locale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.myapp.mobileapp.myapp" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustUnspecified|stateUnspecified">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme="myapp"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.keith.canvascameraplugin.CanvasCameraView" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.ANALYTICS_DISPATCH"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.AnalyticsService"/>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:name="com.google.android.gms.analytics.CampaignTrackingService"/>
        <activity android:exported="true" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushHandlerActivity"/>
        <receiver android:exported="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.myapp.mobileapp"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.GCMIntentService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.PushInstanceIDListenerService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <service android:exported="false" android:name="com.adobe.phonegap.push.RegistrationIntentService"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.scom.ApplicationId" android:value="@string/fb_app_id"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.facebook.scom.ApplicationName" android:value="@string/fb_app_name"/>
        <activity android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize" android:label="@string/fb_app_name" android:name="com.facebook.FacebookActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"/>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <provider android:authorities="com.myapp.mobileapp.google_measurement_service" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementContentProvider"/>
        <receiver android:enabled="true" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.UPLOAD"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService"/>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The funny thing is that a local build of the app works on my Android device, but it does not work after sending it to PhonegapBuild and then send it to Google Play store. Also worth mentioning is the fact that I can run it on my device from PhonegapBuild, but not from the Google Play store.

Some other facts: the app is build using Ionic (and PhonegapBuild).

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Seem you miss   android:versionCode and    android:versionName in your manifest attribute

Comment: Hi Mike, good point, I will remove the previous one (this one is not about AndroidManifest.xml). Thanks for your comment christian, I will dive into that :).